# Controlling 2 socket.io connections

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm working on an app that has 2 types of users. I would like to separate out their functionality in two socket.io files.

index.js:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
require('/sockets/userType1')(io);
require('/sockets/userType2')(io);
```

userType1.js:

```
module.exports = function (io) {
    io.on("connection", function (socket) {
        console.log("Connected to userType1");
    });
}
```

userType2.js

```
module.exports = function (io) {
    io.on("connection", function (socket) {
        console.log("Connected to userType2");
    });
}
```

However when I connect from the client side it connects to both (which I guess I would expect since I don't have anything distinguishing which one I am trying to connect to).

Is there a way to define the connection to only connect to one of those socket.io classes? or do I just need to rely on naming conventions?

Comment: Take a look at [namespaces](https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#namespaces).

Comment: Thanks @robertklep thats exactly what I was looking for

Comment: You can't have two separate socket.io servers attached to the same web server.  Just can't do it that way - they will both see all incoming requests since the client requests for one are indistinguishable from the other.  You would have to either create a new web server on a new port and then connect on a different port for one of the connections or use separate socket.io namespaces like woodsy suggested on just one socket.io server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Socket.io [NAMESPACES](https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#namespaces)

userType1.js:

```
module.exports = function (io) {
    var nsp = io.of('/userType1');
    nsp.on("connection", function (socket) {
        console.log("Connected to userType1");
    });
}
```

userType2.js

```
module.exports = function (io) {
    var nsp = io.of('/userType2');
    nsp.on("connection", function (socket) {
        console.log("Connected to userType2");
    });
}
```

userTypeALLUSERS:

```
module.exports = function (io) {
    io.on("connection", function (socket) {
        console.log("Connected to ALL USERS");
    });
}
```

Client Side (for usertype2):

```
var socket = io('/userType2');
```

server console:

> Connected to userType2
>
> Connected to ALL USERS